# How to copy or configure kafka connect plugin files?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have downloaded plugin files from https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-cdc-microsoft-sql/,

It has three folders lib, etc, doc, manifest.json. etc has connect-avro-docker.properties, mssqlsource.properties, repro.properties. I can add CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH to lib, but what about these config files?

In https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html page they did not give clear instructions on where to copy these files.

How to copy or configure kafka connect plugin files for confluent? 
Any direction is appreciated.

I installed only kafka-connect, schema-registry, kafka-broker, zookeeper. I didn't find a way to install hub on windows.

Comment: Reword the title, add some grammar corrections and add some clarifications to clear some contexts.

Comment: you can just run `confluent-hub install confluentinc/kafka-connect-cdc-mssql:1.0.0-preview` to download and install the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

[The instructions are here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#connect-installing-plugins)

You need to point `plugin.path` line in the Connect properties to the absoulte path of the extracted `lib` folder - the parent folder of where the JARs are located.

You can also [use `confluent-hub` tool](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/confluent-hub/client.html), which should set this all up for you.

Comment: I installed only kafka-connect, schema-registry, kafka-broker, zookeeper. I didn't find a way to install hub on windows
I can add CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH to lib, but what about these config files connect-avro-docker.properties, mssqlsource.properties, repro.properties?

Comment: I don't know what these files are, and they are not needed to get the Connector libraries available for Connect to use. You will only need one configuration to start the actual connector

Comment: You can install Confluent Hub Client from - https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/confluent-hub/client.html

Comment: they only have mac and Linux at https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/confluent-hub/client.html

Comment: Well, those are the supported OS's https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html#operating-systems

Comment: I think I figured it out, will post the solution once I implement it.

Comment: If you're running Kafka Connect on Windows because that's where your database runs, then I would recommend running Connect on a separate Linux machine where you can dedicate resources to it